# css transitions

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I've been building an iphone optimitized version of my site, and have been trying to get animations to work/transitions to work.

I looked at iui/ciui,etc.etc. but they seem like overkill for what I need. I'm using jquery and have most of the functionality built, except that I couldn't get .animate to work smoothly, so I'm trying css transitions.

I have a div which when an object within the div is clicked, I want the div to transition of the page left (standard iPhone UI). 
So as I understand, you can't apply a css transition to a parent element onclick, so I add a class with jquery and the class has the css transition in it.

This works, with the exception that the only css transition that I could get to work is

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-330px, 0);
```

and I don't see a way to add a transition time to this, so this ends up being as effective as .hide(). 
Any ideas?

I couldn't really figure out how the other transitions worked. 
like

```
 -webkit-transition-property:  left;
  -webkit-transition-duration:  4s;
```

how would I specify how far left (and I'm actually going negative numbers). Also, it didn't seem that this was triggered on the add-class.

I've looked at the http://webkit.org/specs/CSSVisualEffects/CSSTransitions.html, but couldn't figure out how to do this based on that documentation.

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Surfin' Safari blog](http://webkit.org/blog/):

- [Post about CSS animations](http://webkit.org/blog/324/css-animation-2/).
- [Post about CSS transitions](http://webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/).
- [Post about CSS transforms](http://webkit.org/blog/130/css-transforms/).

I'm not completely sure that the iPhone supports all those techniques, but the probability is high.

Answer (score 0):

could you not just use a standard css positioning and possibly jquery animations? if not maybe [this](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-VisualEffects) helps?